# negate regex pattern in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

It is possible to negate a regex pattern in Mysql? I know that normally we can negate a pattern using `?!`, but this does not work in Mysql.

What I need to acheive is to negate the result matching some binary like `.0.0..0.`, which means don't count when second, fourth and seventh are Zeros. I can not use `NOT REGEX`, because I am building the mysql procedure, which expected to be used with other condition.

Any idea is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a general solution to nearly all "negative regex" matching questions: turn it into a positive matching problem using some logic.

This is usually easier than trying to construct a regex that matches "everything but this pattern".

In this case, that is quite simple:

```
select * from table
    where column_name regex '[pattern]' = 0
```

Comment: You can also use `not regexp`. [Look here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp).

Comment: You can also do `NOT (any expression)` so `NOT (column_name REGEXP 'pattern')` also works.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use [`NOT REGEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp):

```
SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE column_name NOT REGEX '^your[[:space:]]pattern here'
```

Stolen from [Erick Jimenez's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982570/negate-regex-pattern-in-mysql#comment53826427_16982646). I think it's better than [dan1111's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982570/negate-regex-pattern-in-mysql/16982646#16982646).

You can also do `NOT (any expression)` so `NOT (column_name REGEXP 'pattern')` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `FULLTEXT` index on that column and use [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)