# MySQL- Output an "other" column based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database, case

I am using MySQL REGEXP to assign reviews into different topics and output them into separate columns. The problem is- some reviews may not get assigned to any topic, which is why I need an "Other" column. How do I modify the query below to achieve that?

```
SELECT 
text,
text REGEXP 'keywords' AND text REGEXP 'other keywords' AND .... AS Cleanliness,
text REGEXP 'keywords' AND text REGEXP 'other keywords' AND .... AS Restaurant,
text REGEXP 'keywords' AND text REGEXP 'other keywords' AND .... AS Wifi,
FROM review_table;
```

**Note that a review can belong to multiple topics.**
The end result  should look like this:

[image: The end result will be a view that should look like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be create anoter REGEXP expression that represents the negation of all other expressions. But that can quickly become tedious to maintain.

Another option is to just wrap the query and analyze the results in the outer query to generate the additional column. This should be as simple as:

```
SELECT x.*, (Cleanliness + Food + Wifi = 0) AS Other
FROM (
    --- original query
) x
```

---

Tip: in MySQL, the return value of a condition expression is `1` on success and `0` on failure. This means that this expression:

```
CASE 
    WHEN review REGEXP 'relevant keywords' 
        AND review REGEXP 'additional keywords if necessary' 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END AS 'Cleanliness'
```

Can also be written:

```
(
    review REGEXP 'relevant keywords' 
    AND review REGEXP 'additional keywords if necessary' 
) AS 'Cleanliness'
```

Comment: I went with the second option and it worked. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use the `NOT(expression)` command

```
    CASE 
        WHEN review NOT (REGEXP 'relevant keywords' 
            AND review REGEXP 'additional keywords if necessary' )
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Irrelevant'
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Related: [negate regex pattern in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982570/negate-regex-pattern-in-mysql)